# How can i use distinct with count in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

[image]

The extention method below does not have `Distinct` and `Count`

```
public static IEnumerable<Something> ToFilterModel(this IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    var v = products
        .SelectMany(x => x.ProductVariants)
        .GroupBy(x => x.OptionId)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Key.ToString(),
            Items = x.Select(x => new Item { Id = x.ValueId, Text = x.Value.OptionValue })
        });
    return v;
}
```

Given the input below it should return 2 `Items` rows and not 3, since i am interested for `ValueIds`
and also `Count` by `ValueIds`

[image]

how should i modify it?

More spesifically it should return items with rows 1 and 2 and also

Count equal to 1 for the first row and Count equal to 2 for the second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by **ValueId** the grouped options, like :

```
Items = x
    .GroupBy(y => y.ValueId)
    .Select(z => new Item { Id = z.Key, Text = z.First().Value.OptionValue, Count = z.Count() })
```

The result will be :

```
{
   "Id":1,
   "Items":[
      {
         "Id":1,
         "Text":"text1",
         "Count":1
      },
      {
         "Id":2,
         "Text":"text2",
         "Count":2
      }
   ]
}
```

NOTE : the `Text` is the count of grouped value ids.

The whole code :

```
var v = products
        .SelectMany(x => x.ProductVariants)
        .GroupBy(x => x.OptionId)
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Id = x.Key.ToString(),
            Items = x
                .GroupBy(y => y.ValueId)
                .Select(z => new Item { Id = z.Key, Text = z.First().Value.OptionValue, Count = z.Count() })
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. it seems i have not set my question correctly. How can i also get the text? new Item { Id = z.Key, Text = "xx", Count = z.Count()

Comment: @IAmNotARobot you're welcome! , will be the `z.First().Value.OptionValue` check my update.